# Elegant solution for Split view controller vs Login

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

In a simple app that simply shows a split view controller what is the best way to display a login to the user before the master/detail is displayed and, once login is confirmed, display the split view controller's master/detail?

Is there an elegant way to handle this without having a messy view hierarchy?

I'm using IB to build the views but a programmatic solution is also welcome.

Comment: Change the view controller on the main window once the login is granted?

Comment: Logging in is a separate task to bringing up information from the master to the detail - I would either split the roles up into two VCs as @Desdenova says, or alternatively, keep a single VC and overlay a view over it. They should be separate though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would present a modal view at startup, which you can then configure with login fields. This allows you to keep split view as the root view. In AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, you can add something like:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let modalView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "startupView")
    modalView.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    splitViewController.present(modalView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

after you have configured your split view. This would present a View Controller with identifier "startupView" which you can then configure in Storyboard.

EDIT - you may also wish to set modal view as page sheet or blur the background if you do not wish the user to see any of the master/detail content before login.

Answer (score -1):

After login succeed, you set the root of window to SplitViewController like that:

```
let splitVC = UISplitViewController()
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first
window?.rootViewController = splitVC
```